# Is it possible to sanitize a Datomic database, given that it is a 'value' and does not 'update-in-place'?

Tags: datomic

I am exploring building on top of Datomic. I am sold on the principle of the database 'as a value'. The thing is, we need to be able to provide sanitized copies of the database to our developers to run locally. Any sensitive data which we are required to keep on the correct side of the firewall must not leak out.

With a standard SQL database this is easy: we just have a service inside the firewall which takes a snapshot of the DB and runs some script against it to update-in-place the sensitive value such that my.secret.email@address.com > email00123@address.com etc. Then the sanitised DB is made available to the developer to lift out of the compliance zone.

However, my understanding of Datomic (and its very strength) is that nothing is ever updated in place. So how would it be possible to sanitise a Datomic DB? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is one use case for [filtering databases](http://docs.datomic.com/filters.html#filtering-for-security) in Datomic. Filtering for security reasons is also discussed in [this talk by Nubank](https://youtu.be/7lm3K8zVOdY?t=18m37s).

The operational model is a bit different from the SQL world because user access and authorization and authentication, etc. are not baked into the database to the same degree. Any peer participates in the database fully and can submit transactions, etc., request an unfiltered database, etc. as API calls. You need an additional application layer (i.e. to create a client for your peer-as-a-server and only expose endpoints for queries against the filtered database) if you want stronger security guarantees.